# Redactor JS - validate form using BootstrapValidator

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, validation, redactor

I'm having a Rails app where I use [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) for rich text input. The form is placed inside a Bootstrap modal. I want to validate (presence) while the user types, and show a validation error if the field is empty. I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com) for the validation part. I currently don't get any validation messages for the `redactor` text area.

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
= form_for idea, remote: remote, html: {role: :form, "data-model" => 'idea', multipart: true}  do |f|

  # This field  / validation works
  .form-group
    = f.label :title, "Title", :class => "required"
    = f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control"

  # This does not
  .form-group
    = f.label :description, :class => "required"
    = f.text_area :description, :class => "form-control big-text-area redactor"
```

And the Javascript looks like this:

```
:javascript

  $('#new_idea').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',

    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'fa fa-check-square',
      invalid: 'fa fa-warning',
      validating: 'fa fa-circle-o-notch spin'
    },

    fields: {
      "idea[title]": {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The title is required'
          }
        }
      },

      "idea[description]": {
        validators: {
          callback: {
            message: 'The idea description is required',
            callback: function(value, validator) {

              # NOTE: This part of the code never get called                 

              var code = $('[name="idea[description]"]').code();
              return (code !== '' && code !== '<p><br></p>');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  $('.redactor').redactor({

    keyupCallback: function (e) {
      validateEditor();
    }
  });

  function validateEditor() {
    $('#new_idea').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', "idea[description]");
  };
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get the validation to work?

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working?

Comment: @Nobita I've updated my question, basically: I currently don't get any validation messages for the redactor text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into something similar when using Redactor so perhaps this will help. In my case, I had a change listener on the textarea to which Redactor was bound to (a similar approach to what I believe Bootstrap Validator is doing) but the problem was that Redactor was eating the *change* event on the original textarea. To get around this, I implemented the following when initializing the Redactor plugin.

```
var $mytextarea = $('selector-for-textarea');
$mytextarea.redactor({
    changeCallback: function( html ) {
        $mytextarea.trigger( 'change' );
    } 
});
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't change anything for me. I get the callback from `keyupCallback` in the redactor form. Like this: `keyupCallback: function (e) {
      console.log("It logs here");
      validateEditor();
    }`, and `validateEditor()` get called. But the `callback:` validation for my `Redactor` text-area never gets called.

Comment: Actually you were partly right. `changeCallback` was the proper method to use, `keyupCallback` didn't catch backspaces. I also had to add `excluded: [],` to `bootstrapValidator`. And instead of `callback: function(value, validator)` I used `notEmpty`.